# Extract Time from Datetime SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, time, type-conversion

I want to get only Time from a DateTime column using SQL query using SQL Server 2012:

The datetime format in the column at the moment is:

**dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm**

**example - 16/10/2018 11:50**

I want to extract the hh:mm and convert the column to a time format (hh:mm or hh:mm:ss)

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the column is a string, do you simply want this?

```
select convert(time, right(col, 5))
```

Answer (score 12):

do cast

```
select cast(datecol as time) [time]
from t
```